# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockStoragePolicySpi

Tags: azure, apache-storm, azure-hdinsight

I am getting the error below after deploying my topology in HDInsight (3.4 Linux) with Storm 0.10.0:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockStoragePolicySpi

Which jar will contain the BlockStoragePolicySpi class?